# Filtering Kendo Grid Array Column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid that I am using to display a typescript structure that looks like this.

`{
    companyId: string,
    name: string,
    inceptionDate: Date,
    tags: string[]
}`

I would like to be able to filter on the tags column, but I am unsure as to how this should actually work.  I can quite easily filter on the name column, either with the built in grid filtering functionality or via code:

`baseFilter.filters.push({ field: "name", operator: "contains", value: "myValue" });`

But I don't see a way to do this against an array object.  I would prefer to be able to select a tag from the a list in the grid filter option, but if that's not possible I'd be quite happy to use a multiselect and set the filter manually.

Is this something that is built in or that is relatively easy (or even just not insanely hard) to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TerminalSamurai's answer did the trick for me !

Here is my full code (with checking if there is already a filter existing)

```
var grid = $("#GridListeModelesDocumentPatient_@Model.PatientId").data("kendoGrid");

        if (grid != null) {

            var filterHandler = grid.dataSource.filter();

            if (dataItem.Nom == "Tous") {
                if (filterHandler != null) {
                    var existingFilters = filterHandler.filters;

                    for (var i = existingFilters.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        if (existingFilters[i].field == "ModelesMotifs") {
                            existingFilters.splice(i, 1);
                        }
                    }
                    grid.dataSource.filter(existingFilters);

                } else {
                    grid.dataSource.filter({});
                }
            } else {
                if (filterHandler != null) {
                    var existingFilters = filterHandler.filters;
                    for (var i = existingFilters.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        if (existingFilters[i].field == "ModelesMotifs") {
                            existingFilters.splice(i, 1);
                        }
                    }
                    var new_filter = {
                        field: "ModelesMotifs",
                        operator: function (modelesMotifs, value) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < modelesMotifs.length; i++) {
                                var modeleMotif = modelesMotifs[i];
                                if (modeleMotif.MotifId === value)
                                    return true;
                            }

                            return false;
                        },
                        value: dataItem.MotifId
                    };
                    existingFilters.push(new_filter);
                    grid.dataSource.filter(existingFilters);
                } else {
                    grid.dataSource.filter({
                        field: "ModelesMotifs",
                        operator: function (modelesMotifs, value) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < modelesMotifs.length; i++) {
                                var modeleMotif = modelesMotifs[i];
                                if (modeleMotif.MotifId === value)
                                    return true;
                            }

                            return false;
                        },
                        value: dataItem.MotifId
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

As long as you're doing the client side filtering, you can use a function for the `operator` field.

a simple example (in js):

```
baseFilter.filters.push({
    field: "tags",
    operator: function (tags, value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
            var tag = tags[i];
            if (tag === value)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }});
```